# Launching an app in a specific display in Mavericks

Tags: mac, macos

I have recently set up dual monitors on my mac mini and am happy with the set up.

However applications such as the very useful Alfred or other applications automatically open up in the second display which is not the behavior I am looking for. Is there a method to allow the application to launch in the other display?

I have seen a method whereby the user can add a second deskspace and then control click the icon in the dock so that a particular space is selected for launching apps but Alfred doesnt appear in the dock so this isn't an option.

Any help appreciated